# How to import a length variable text file to excel with VBA and split it in several columns?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first question for this community.

I would like to know how to import a length variable text file (from a bash script) to Excel with VBA and split it in several columns. I'm learning to  use VBA and cannot figure it out yet. This is what I have:

Servers list from script:

[image: Servers list from script]

This the output I need in excel:

[image: Servers arranged]

The fields "Day" and "%Idle" will be added by the VBA macro.

The numbers from 6 to 11 will be added manually, so there is no problem there.

Thanks in advance and kind regards to everyone!

Comment: Import the data as is, record a macro doing this for one of the chunks and work from there. Really neither of these formats is great for data though. It's like taking it from one non relational form and putting it into another.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks! I will try that now and will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work (depending on how much the structure of your data/servers list varies).

You will need to change the value of `FILE_PATH` in the function `splitTextFileByServer` (below) to wherever it is on your machine.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub WriteServerListToSheet()
    Dim logsSplitByServer() As String
    logsSplitByServer = splitTextFileByServer()

    Dim interimArray() As String
    Dim outputArray() As Variant: ReDim outputArray(1 To 8, 1 To 2)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

        Dim serverIndex As Long
        Dim readIndex As Long
        Dim outputColumnOffset As Long

        For serverIndex = LBound(logsSplitByServer) To UBound(logsSplitByServer)
            interimArray = VBA.Strings.Split(logsSplitByServer(serverIndex), vbNewLine, -1, vbBinaryCompare)
            If (UBound(interimArray) + 1) <> UBound(outputArray) Then ' (+1) as interimArray is 0-based
                ReDim outputArray(1 To (UBound(interimArray) + 2), 1 To 2) '(+2) as 0-based and we want a row for headers: Day, %Idle
            End If

            ' Assume first item in interimArray is: server***
            outputArray(1, 1) = interimArray(LBound(interimArray))
            outputArray(2, 1) = "Day"
            outputArray(2, 2) = "%Idle"

            For readIndex = (LBound(interimArray) + 1) To UBound(interimArray)
                outputArray(2 + readIndex, 2) = interimArray(readIndex) ' (2 + ... as we want to skip first 2 rows
            Next readIndex

            .Offset(0, outputColumnOffset).Resize(UBound(outputArray, 1), UBound(outputArray, 2)).Value2 = outputArray
            outputColumnOffset = outputColumnOffset + 3 ' Change this if you decide to add columns
        Next serverIndex

    End With

End Sub

Private Function splitTextFileByServer() As String()
    Const FILE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\serverslist.txt"

    If Len(VBA.FileSystem.Dir$(FILE_PATH)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("No file exists at: " & FILE_PATH)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim fileContents As String
    ' Read file into memory; assumes it will fit.
    Open FILE_PATH For Binary Access Read As #1
    fileContents = VBA.Strings.Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, 1, fileContents
    Close #1

    Dim outputArray() As String
    outputArray = VBA.Strings.Split(fileContents, "########################################" & vbNewLine, -1, vbBinaryCompare)

    splitTextFileByServer = outputArray
End Function
```

If it doesn't work, let me know why/what's wrong with the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @chillin
I will try it right now! I've tried to record the macro and it worked nice but it breaks when I have lots of records. I will try your solution! Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: To be honest, I tried to apply your code but could not figure out at first. I ended implementing an 'if' inside a 'while' loop in order to hurry the task since it was for an urgent report. I'm trying to implement your code to mine as I understand it since, as I told before, I'm still learning VBA. Anyway thanks a lot for your answer, really appreciate it! If someone is interested in the code I created I can post it here. It is very specific for my case but I can hand it over without problems. Thanks all!